# r package installed properly but "there is no package called ‘DiabetesTxPath-master" error

Tags: r

I'm trying to install a package called "DiabetesTxPath-master" from local files.(The file can be downloaded in https://github.com/rohit43/DiabetesTxPath)
I used the code below installing it.

```
'filename<-"DiabetesTxPath-master.zip"'
install.packages(filename,type="binary",repos=NULL)
```

but when I try  to load the packaged by the code below, 
    library(DiabetesTxPath)
error comes up.
    there is no package called ‘DiabetesTxPath-master'

1. There is no problem in location.

   > .libPaths()
   >   [1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.2/library"'

and this is where I want my package to be installed.
(and I see my packaged installed in the folder with my eyes!)

2.I've also tried to run as an administrator. it didn't work either.

So what could be the probelm, and how could I fix this?

Any comment would be appreciated so much.
I've been trying it so hard for a week.

Comment: What was the output from your `install.packages()` call, can you include that in your question? I suspect the package didn't install properly.

Comment: @Marius I didn't use `install.packages()` to install the package. I tried to install it by local file. and when i tried `install_github()`, it gave an error `Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : 
  Failed to connect to api.github.com port 80: Timed out`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
library(devtools)
install_github("rohit43/DiabetesTxPath")
```

the problem arises because the dependencies for this package

> ERROR: dependencies 'FeatureExtraction', 'CohortMethod',
>   'OhdsiSharing' are not available for package 'DiabetesTxPath'
>   are not available for this package in R 3.5 and above .

Now you need to install  older version of R where these dependencies were supported and try using the above method.

Comment: Installing an old version won't work. Those packages don't exist at all, for old or new versions of R. This package cannot be installed because it has dependencies that themselves cannot be installed (because they don't exist, or if they do, it's not clear where they are).

Comment: Actually, these packages are available on github: https://github.com/OHDSI/FeatureExtraction. But I was unable to install them.

Comment: then you need to install them before installing this package this will work

Comment: Thank you very much. when I tried the code you gave, another error came up : > install_github("rohit43/DiabetesTxPath")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : 
  Failed to connect to api.github.com port 80: Timed out
Why is it happening? Is it because of the server I am using?

Comment: I'm actually trying to install the package in the server that's not connected to the internet. and in that server, all the packages need to be installed before are already installed, and the R version is 3.4.2. So there should be no problem, right?

Comment: you need to install rtools first and intall curl also you will not find this error. for R 3.4.2 you have to check whether this package were part of them or noto

Comment: `@Hunaidkhan` you mean `install.packages("curl")`? I've already installed it and this package is also for R 3.4.2..

Comment: 1st install rtools from  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/